# Serialization of structure with OPENSSL Signatures

Tags: c, serialization, openssl, signatures

I am doing serialization of a structure in C but I am having a problem which I can figure it out:s The code is a bit long but I think it is ok to understand.

This is the top level structure I am trying to serialize:

```
typedef struct 
{
    uint8_t protocol_version;
    ContentType signed_content_type;
    signedDATA signed_data;
}data1609Dot2SignData;
```

Contentype and signedDATA are other structures as defined bellow:

```
typedef enum
{
    UNSECURED,
    SIGNED,
    ENCRYPTED,
    CERTIFICATE_REQUEST,
    CERTIFICATE_RESPONSE,
    ANONYMOUS_CERTIFICATE_RESPONSE,
    CERTIFICATE_REQUEST_ERROR,  
    CRL_REQUEST,
    CRL,
    SIGNED_PARTIAL_PAYLOAD,
    SIGNED_EXTERNAL_PAYLOAD,
    SIGNED_WSA,
    CERTIFICATE_RESPONSE_ACKNOWLEDGMENT
}ContentType;

typedef struct
{
    ToBeSignedDATA unsigned_data;
    Signature signature;
}signedDATA;

typedef struct
{
    Psid psid;
    octet_string data;
}ToBeSignedDATA;

typedef uint32_t Psid;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t length;
    char* content;
} octet_string;

typedef struct
{
    PKAlgorithm algorithm;
    ECDSA_SIG* sig; 
}Signature;

typedef enum
{
    ECDSA_NISTP224_WITH_SHA224,
    ECDSA_NISTP256_WITH_SHA256,
    ECIES_NISTP256
}PKAlgorithm;
```

I created 2 functions one to serialize and another to deserialize:

```
int serialize1609Dot2DATA(data1609Dot2SignData x,char** buffer)
{

    printf(" Serialize: (sig->r, sig->s): (%s,%s)\n", BN_bn2hex(x.signed_data.signature.sig->r), BN_bn2hex(x.signed_data.signature.sig->s));

    const size_t msg_data_len = x.signed_data.unsigned_data.data.length;    // size of data.

    char* sig_big_num_r;
    char* sig_big_num_s;

    unsigned char* to_r;
    unsigned char* to_s;

    int size_sig_r, size_sig_s = 0;
    sig_big_num_r = BN_bn2hex(x.signed_data.signature.sig->r);
    sig_big_num_s = BN_bn2hex(x.signed_data.signature.sig->s);

    size_sig_r = strlen(sig_big_num_r);
    size_sig_s = strlen(sig_big_num_s);

    printf("Size of converted signature r: %d\n", size_sig_r);
    printf("Size of converted signature s: %d\n", size_sig_s);

    printf("Data sig r: %s\n", sig_big_num_r);
    printf("Data sig s: %s\n", sig_big_num_s);
    int serialize_size = 0;
    serialize_size = sizeof(x.protocol_version) + sizeof(x.signed_content_type) + size_sig_r + size_sig_s + sizeof(x.signed_data.signature.algorithm) + sizeof(x.signed_data.unsigned_data.psid) + msg_data_len + sizeof(uint32_t); 
// an adicional sizeof(uint32_t) is added to store the size of the data.
    *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*serialize_size);

    if(*buffer)
    {
        size_t offset = 0;

        memcpy(*buffer+offset, &msg_data_len, sizeof(size_t));      // size of the data field is stored here.
        offset += sizeof(size_t);

        memcpy(*buffer+offset, &x.protocol_version, sizeof(x.protocol_version));    // protocol version
        offset += sizeof(x.protocol_version);

        memcpy(*buffer+offset, &x.signed_content_type, sizeof(x.signed_content_type)); // signed content type
        offset += sizeof(x.signed_content_type);

        strcpy(*buffer+offset, sig_big_num_r);                                        //    Sig r
        offset += size_sig_r;           

        strcpy(*buffer+offset, sig_big_num_s);                                        // Sig s
        offset += size_sig_s;

        memcpy(*buffer+offset, &x.signed_data.signature.algorithm, sizeof(x.signed_data.signature.algorithm));  // algorithm
        offset += sizeof(x.signed_data.signature.algorithm);

        memcpy(*buffer+offset, &x.signed_data.unsigned_data.psid, sizeof(x.signed_data.unsigned_data.psid)); // PSID
        offset += sizeof(x.signed_data.unsigned_data.psid);

        memcpy(*buffer+offset, &x.signed_data.unsigned_data.data.content, msg_data_len);        // data.
        offset += msg_data_len;     
    }
    return serialize_size;
}
```

and this is my desserialize function:

```
data1609Dot2SignData* deserialize1609Dot2DATA(char* serialdata)
{
    data1609Dot2SignData* y = 0;

    y = malloc(sizeof(data1609Dot2SignData)); // must be the size of thebuffer?

    if(y)
    {
        size_t offset = 0;

        memcpy(&y->signed_data.unsigned_data.data.length, (serialdata + offset), sizeof(y->signed_data.unsigned_data.data.length));
        offset += sizeof(y->signed_data.unsigned_data.data.length);

        int data_len = y->signed_data.unsigned_data.data.length;
        printf("DATA LEN in DESERIALIZED 1609dot2 function: %d\n", data_len);

        memcpy(&y->protocol_version, (serialdata + offset), sizeof(y->protocol_version));
        offset += sizeof(y->protocol_version);

        printf("Protocol_version in DESERIALIZED 1609dot2 function: %d\n", y->protocol_version);

        memcpy(&y->signed_content_type, (serialdata + offset), sizeof(y->signed_content_type));
        offset += sizeof(y->signed_content_type);

        printf("Signed content type in DESERIALIZED 1609dot2 function: %d\n", y->signed_content_type);

        //y->signed_data.signature.sig->r = malloc(32);
        char* tmp_sig_r = malloc(64);
        char* tmp_sig_s = malloc(64);
        ECDSA_SIG* sig;

        memcpy(tmp_sig_r, (serialdata + offset), 64);
        offset += 64; //
        BN_hex2bn(&sig->r, tmp_sig_r);

        memcpy(tmp_sig_s, (serialdata + offset), 64);
        offset += 64;
        BN_hex2bn(&sig->s, tmp_sig_s);     // SEGMENTATION FAULT HERE. 

        printf(" Deserialize: (sig->r, sig->s): (%s,%s)\n",tmp_sig_r ,tmp_sig_s);

        memcpy(&y->signed_data.signature.algorithm, (serialdata + offset), sizeof(y->signed_data.signature.algorithm));
        offset += sizeof(y->signed_data.signature.algorithm);

        printf("Algorithm in DESERIALIZED 1609dot2 function: %d\n", y->signed_data.signature.algorithm);

        memcpy(&y->signed_data.unsigned_data.psid, (serialdata + offset), sizeof(y->signed_data.unsigned_data.psid));
        offset += sizeof(y->signed_data.unsigned_data.psid);

        printf("PSID in DESERIALIZED 1609dot2 function: %d\n", y->signed_data.unsigned_data.psid);

        y->signed_data.unsigned_data.data.content = malloc(data_len);
        memcpy(y->signed_data.unsigned_data.data.content, (serialdata + offset), data_len);
        offset += data_len;

//  printf(" Deserialize: (sig->r, sig->s): (%s,%s)\n", BN_bn2hex(y->signed_data.signature.sig->r), BN_bn2hex(y->signed_data.signature.sig->s));
    printf("FINAL\n");
    }
    return y;
}
```

I am getting Segmentation fault on the function BN_hex2_bn in the desserialize function. I have it commented on the code. I can not understand why I get this error only in the assign of the sig->s and not in the sig->r. I have been stuck to this for weeks:s hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't you use ECDSA_SIG sig; instead of ECDSA_SIG* sig; ? Since you are not using malloc on this pointer.

The description of the function BN_hex2bn:
BN_hex2bn() converts the string str containing a hexadecimal number to a BIGNUM and stores it in **bn. If *bn is NULL , a new BIGNUM is created.

So before using it, you need to make sure that the destiny is NULL or allocated. try this:

```
    ECDSA_SIG sig;

    memset(&sig,0,sizeof(ECDSA_SIG ));

    memcpy(tmp_sig_r, (serialdata + offset), 64);
    offset += 64; //
    BN_hex2bn(&sig.r, tmp_sig_r);

    memcpy(tmp_sig_s, (serialdata + offset), 64);
    offset += 64;
    BN_hex2bn(&sig.s, tmp_sig_s);
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it is not working also:s I used gdb and I get an error on  BN_set_word(), which I supposed it is called from the BN_hex2bn() function.

Comment: try using memset in the sig structure or assigning NULL directly to r and s, before calling BN_hex2bn.

Comment: The problem was as you said, related with the allocation of the memory, after that is allocated, the code compiled correctly. Thank you so much.